# How could submarines be put underneath very thick glaciers with (relatively) low technology?

Tags: science-based, technology, glaciers

So in this scenario, some people need to put (large) submarines under very thick glacial ice, thicker than Antarctica, ~4km on average & in thicker areas it get get to 6-8km, the thinnest areas that still allow access are ~2.3 to 3km thick. Underneath this extremely thick ice there is a significant amount of liquid water which is mostly around ~2,850 meters to ~4,900 meters deep underneath it.

The submarines are designed similar to bathyscaphes, however they are far larger, being most commonly in the 1,500-2,500 tonne range of size rather than the sub 100 ton size range of real bathyscaphes, kept together using fictional technology that's hard to explain & i haven't fully figured out yet. Enabled by a fictional resource.

The environment is in complete darkness 8 months of the year & about 1 month more with practically none, so anything using the sun is off the table most of the year. Although if it is too difficult to do without the sun it is still possible to use it.

The technology available isn't that low tech, but still lower tech than today, roughly the technology of the mid 1960s. Any openings made can be kept open without major issue due to other fictional technologies.

Under these conditions, with mid 1960s technology, if possible what would the best possible way be to get under the ice to deliver submarines?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use composites.

Comment: Minor point: just as magma that exits a volcano is now lava, a glacier that is on water is either an ice sheet or (if it calves) an iceberg.  Glaciers are on land.  (Unless you're referring to a subglacial lake, rather than a glacier on an ocean.)

Comment: Do the submarines need to be retrievable afterwards?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica you can look at images from the recovered pieces of the sub. Notice which parts of it did not fail xD

Comment: I had to read this twice to realize it's about the drilling (etc.) technology rather than the submersible craft themselves.

Comment: What diameter are these subs? 100cm? 1m? 10m? I would say 1m is pushing current tech limits. Considering what glaciers do, why has the lake basin not been broken and lake drained? That is it is more reasonable to assume submarines under oceanic ice sheet rather then the implied inland. This distinction of trying to access an inland body of water should be made explicit.

Answer (score 10):

Since you've mentioned the 1960s...

**Nuclear for everything!**

Okay, jokes aside - I'm serious - Either the use of nuclear weapons drilled into the ice to blow a hole in it, or the more practical (but boring... heh.) using some form of nuclear reactor-powered drill to melt/drill a hole.

As far as mining goes - I believe in the 1960s there were mine shafts as deep as 2-2.5 km below the surface, so all the necessary 'tech' is there.

But yeah, if you are going for that time period, make it some zany nuclear-related thing, because everything in the 60s was about the Atomic Age.

Comment: This would be my answer too: use a miniaturised reactor generate massive amounts of heat, direct hot water downwards with pump and a nozzle, melt the ice under them, and let gravity do the rest.

Comment: I was going to point out that the first American nuclear submarine, *Nautilus*, went below the Arctic ice cap in 1958.  No, *Nautilus* couldn't take several km of water pressure -- but that was because submarine warfare in that time never needed depths below 300 m.

Comment: Wasnt there a proposed mission to Ganymede which would have used a nuclear heated drill to go make a long tunnel into the subsurface oceans ? Seems like that would be the most straight forward way of going about this, though it depends on how the ice moves internally.

Comment: My back of the envelope calculations indicate in the mid-10^14 J at a *minimum* to melt that much ice.  That's about two trainloads of coal but of course getting a train onto a glacier is difficult.  It's the energy output of a large nuclear reactor for about a week.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible with 1950's technology.

The [Trieste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trieste_(bathyscaphe)) is a bathyscaphe. It was built in 1953, and was still the best vehicle in 1963 to search for the wreck of the USS Thresher. However, the inhabited part of the Trieste was the ball you see slung below it. It is shaped a bit like a submarine, but it is not really designed for going distances. If you want to have something that people can live in for a year, you are going to have to scale it up a lot. But it was good enough for its purpose.

The [USS Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Nautilus_(SSN-571)) was launched in 1954. It had a crew of 116. It was nuclear-powered, and broke many submarine endurance records. In its trip to the North Pole, it stayed submerged for a week. This is not 8 months. If we are going to stay under the ice for 8 months, we are going to need some way of recycling air.

The longest published unsupported underwater stay patrol 111 days by HMS Warspite in 1982. There are problems with maintaining an atmosphere and storing or eliminating waste which may not have been solved in the 1950s but I don't think they depend on any wholly new technology.

Nuclear power would seem to be the preferred solution. However, there was a proposal in the 1980's for an Italian long-range submarine that would be powered on hydrogen and oxygen, stored in a double hull that acted as a cylinder. This would be a lot smaller than a conventional nuclear submarine, and might have had a crew of 2 or 3.

We have to get through the ice. There are plans to explore Europa using [nuclear tunnelling robots](https://www.universetoday.com/158774/if-were-going-to-get-under-the-ice-on-europa-how-will-we-send-a-signal-back-to-the-surface/). This is a modern proposal, but the technology would have been understood back in the fifties. You can melt or crush the ice below you, pump it to the back, and allow it to re-freeze. For this, the submarine would probably be vertical to keep the cross-section small.

I think we could make something that might do the job using mostly 1950s technology without stretching things too far. The main problems lie outside the device itself. How do 1950s people survive on an ice planet? If they live at the equator, is there an edge to the ice field? Where do they get the metal to build this thing if they are on a water world where all the heavy stuff goes to the bottom?

Comment: It's a mostly normal planet with a very harsh southern ice cap, almost everything they have is transported from more normal climates for people further north

Comment: If I was in a submarine, I would look very hard for an edge to the ice sheet, so I could go in a small way and come back. You can probably have a deep-diving, ice-boring submarine that can stay down for months, but doing all at once is pretty hairy.

Answer (score 2):

A [hot spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_spring) could create an opening of warm-enough water in the middle of an ice sheet. The groundwater is heated by magma or radioactive decay, the heat causes it to rise, and causes a part of the ice sheet to melt. Hot springs are commonly seen on land, but [can occur underwater too](http://www.waterencyclopedia.com/Ge-Hy/Hot-Springs-on-the-Ocean-Floor.html).

So you just need a hot spring to make an opening wide enough to fit your submarine, and no technology is needed. Except the technology for building your submarine, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

James Bond style underwater caves opening into a base in contact with the surface.

[image]

The submarine would navigate a tunnel to go between the base and the open waters.

The cave offers also the advantage of being protected by air raid and espionage from the thick layer or rocks above it.

Answer (score 1):

## IceCube

Read about the [installation of the detector strings for the IceCube neutrino observatory in Antarctica](https://icecube.wisc.edu/news/detector/2014/12/drilling-icecube-story-of-innovation-expertise-and-strong-will/).  They drilled 2.5 km boreshafts through the Antarctic ice sheet using specialized drills that sprayed hot water. Their shafts were quite a bit smaller than a submarine, but they had the huge disadvantage that the shaft had to remain liquid the whole time the string is being deployed.

I read your question as "how do you put the subs below the ice sheet", and infer that they do not need to come back up later. That means having the top of the shaft start to freeze over before the sub reaches the bottom should be OK. That in turn means the sub could be its own drill.

[image: IceCube string installation shaft]

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to make a hole in the ice (and have some other technology that will keep it opened), then the solution is very simple: just put a stash of coal on top of the ice and put it on fire. By stash of coal I mean train-loads of coal. The intense fire will melt and evaporate the ice down to the bottom. Once the hole starts deepening you'll have to throw additional coal into the hole. Proper oxygen access might be difficult, but this issue can be solved in a few ways. Firstly, you can always make the hole wide enough to have good oxygen access by using more coal. Alternatively, you can drill two parallel holes interconnected by horizontal shafts with fire alternating between them. Once you get to the bottom, it remains to lower the submarine through the hole 4km down - gonna be challenging ;)

Comment: You *may* have a problem with the melt water not evaporating fast enough to avoid dousing your fire...